# Etymology of Romance words for Marriage

Tags: etymology, romance-languages

There are a few different Romance etyma with the meaning 'marriage'.  Some are derived from Latin *casa* 'house', some from *mater* 'mother', and some from *mas/maris* 'man':

L ***casa*** [+ ***-mentum***] >  CA *casament*, ES *casamiento*, PT *casamento*,  RO  *căsătorie*

L ***mater*** + ***-monium*** = ***matrimonium*** > CA *matrimoni*, ES/IT *matrimonio*, FR *matrimoine*, PT *matrimónio*, RO *matrimoniu*

L ***maris*** + -***aticum*** > FR *mariage*

For the origins of the word coming from "casa" in these languages, the word could literally be translated in to English as 'housement'.

Specifically, I have a hunch that the word would have originally meant the joining of two houses as this is what marriage typically meant in more traditional societies.  However, I could be wrong and the house portion of the word could just refer to the household of the husband and wife. What is the significance of the root "casa" as a part of the word's etymology?

Comment: This question is not "language specific". It is about Romance etymology.

Answer (score 3):

In Italian there is a verb accasare “to marry”, and a noun accasamento “marriage”, etymologically “taking to the house, taking home”. This is evidently the basic meaning of the forms that you have cited.

Comment: So, in other words, you feel that these words don't relate to the joining of houses, but rather the husband and wife (or otherwise) taking to a house together.is that fair to say?

Comment: Yes, because they involve the Latin preposition "ad".